# Structurally enforced Free Alternative, without left distributivity

Tags: haskell, category-theory, free-monad, alternative-functor, abstract-algebra

There is a nice [Free Alternative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Alternative-Free.html) in the great *free* package, which lifts a Functor to a left-distributive Alternative.

That is, the claim is that:

```
runAlt :: Alternative g => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> Alt f a -> g a
```

is an *Alternative homomorphism*, with `liftAlt`.  And, indeed, it *is* one, but only for [*left-distributive*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Laws_6) Alternative instances.

Of course, in reality, very few Alternative instances are actually left-distributive.  Most of the alternative instances that actually matter (parsers, MaybeT f for most Monad f, etc.) are not left-distributive.  This fact can be shown by an example where `runAlt` and `liftAlt` do not form an Alternative homomorphism:

```
(writeIORef x False <|> writeIORef True) *> (guard =<< readIORef x)
-- is an IO action that throws an exception
runAlt id $ (liftAlt (writeIORef x False) <|> liftAlt (writeIORef True))
               *> liftAlt (guard =<< readIORef x)
-- is an IO action that throws no exception and returns successfully ()
```

So `runAlt` is only an Alternative homomorphism for some Alternatives, but not all.  This is because the structure of `Alt` *normalizes* all actions to distribute over the left.

`Alt` is great because, structurally, `Alt f` is a lawful `Applicative` and `Alternative`.  There isn't any possible way to construct a value of type `Alt f a` using the Applicative and Alternative functions that don't follow the laws...the structure of the type itself is what makes it a free Alternative.

Just like, for lists, you can't construct a list using `<>` and `mempty` that doesn't respect `x <> mempty = x`, `mempty <> x = x`, and associativity.

I've written a Free alternative that *doesn't* enforce the Applicative and Alternative laws, structurally, but *does* yield a valid Alternative and Applicative homomorphism with runAlt/liftAlt:

```
data Alt :: (* -> *) -> * -> * where
    Pure  :: a   -> Alt f a
    Lift  :: f a -> Alt f a
    Empty :: Alt f a
    Ap    :: Alt f (a -> b) -> Alt f a -> Alt f b
    Plus  :: Alt f as -> Alt f as -> Alt f as

instance Functor f => Functor (Alt f) where
    fmap f = \case
      Pure x     -> Pure (f x)
      Lift x     -> Lift (f <$> x)
      Empty      -> Empty
      Ap fs xs   -> Ap ((f .) <$> fs) xs
      Plus xs ys -> Plus (f <$> xs) (f <$> ys)

instance Functor f => Applicative (Alt f) where
    pure  = Pure
    (<*>) = Ap

instance Functor f => Alternative (Alt f) where
    empty = Empty
    (<|>) = Plus
```

structurally, `Alt f` is not an actual `Applicative`, because:

```
pure f <*> pure x = Ap (Pure f) (Pure x)
pure (f x)        = Pure (f x)
```

So `pure f <*> pure x` is not the same as `pure (f x)`, structurally.  Not a valid Applicative, right off the bat.

*But*, with the given `runAlt` and `liftAlt`:

```
liftAlt :: f a -> Alt f a
liftAlt = Lift

runAlt :: Alternative g => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> Alt f a -> g a
runAlt f = \case
  Pure x     -> pure x
  Lift x     -> f x
  Empty      -> empty
  Ap fs xs   -> runAlt f fs <*> runAlt f xs
  Plus xs ys -> runAlt f xs <|> runAlt f ys
```

And `runAlt` here does indeed act as a valid Applicative homomorphism with a given natural transformation...

One could say that my new `Alt f` is a valid Alternative and Applicative when quotiented by the equivalence relationship defined by `runAlt`, i suppose.

Anyway, this is only slightly unsatisfying.  Is there any way to write a free Alternative that is *structurally* a valid Alternative and Applicative, *without* enforcing left distributivity?

(In particular, I'm actually interested in one that follows the [left catch](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Laws_6) law, and enforces it structurally.  This would be a separate and also interesting thing, but not completely necessary.)

And, if there isn't any way, why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Control.Alternative.Free`'s `Alt f` produces a left-distributive `Alternative` for free, even if `f` isn't `Alternative` or `f` is a non-left-distributive `Alternative`. We can say that, in addition to the well-agreed upon alternative laws

```
empty <|> x = x
x <|> empty = x
(x <|> y) <|> z = x <|> (y <|> z)
empty <*> f = empty
```

`Alt f` also gives left-distribution for free.

```
(a <|> b) <*> c = (a <*> c) <|> (b <*> c)
```

Because `Alt f` is always left distributive (and `runAlt . liftAlt = id`) `liftAlt` can never be a homomorphism for non-left-distributive `Alternative`s. If an `Alternative f` is not left-distributive, then there exist `a`, `b`, and `c` such that

```
(a <|> b) <*> c != (a <*> c) <|> (b <*> c)
```

If `liftAlt : f -> Alt f` were a homomorphism then

```
                  (a <|> b) <*> c  !=                   (a <*> c) <|> (b <*> c)                                       -- f is not left-distributive
id               ((a <|> b) <*> c) != id               ((a <*> c) <|> (b <*> c))
runAlt . liftAlt ((a <|> b) <*> c) != runAlt . liftAlt ((a <*> c) <|> (b <*> c))                                      -- runAlt . liftAlt = id
runAlt ((liftAlt a <|> liftAlt b) <*> liftAlt c) != runAlt ((liftAlt a <*> liftAlt c) <|> (liftAlt b <*> liftAlt c))  -- homomorphism
runAlt ((liftAlt a <|> liftAlt b) <*> liftAlt c) != runAlt ((liftAlt a <|> liftAlt b) <*> liftAlt c)                  -- by left-distribution of `Alt`, this is a contradiction
```

To demonstrate this we need an `Alternative` that isn't left-distributive. Here's one, `FlipAp []`.

```
newtype FlipAp f a = FlipAp {unFlipAp :: f a}
  deriving Show

instance Functor f => Functor (FlipAp f) where
    fmap f (FlipAp x) = FlipAp (fmap f x)

instance Applicative f => Applicative (FlipAp f) where
    pure = FlipAp . pure
    (FlipAp f) <*> (FlipAp xs) = FlipAp ((flip ($) <$> xs) <*> f)

instance Alternative f => Alternative (FlipAp f) where
    empty = FlipAp empty
    (FlipAp a) <|> (FlipAp b) = FlipAp (a <|> b)
```

Along with some laws for left distribution and right distribution, and some examples

```
leftDist :: Alternative f => f (x -> y) -> f (x -> y) -> f x -> Example (f y)
leftDist a b c = [(a <|> b) <*> c, (a <*> c) <|> (b <*> c)]

rightDist :: Alternative f => f (x -> y) -> f x -> f x -> Example (f y)
rightDist a b c = [a <*> (b <|> c), (a <*> b) <|> (a <*> c)]

type Example a = [a]

ldExample1 :: Alternative f => Example (f Int)
ldExample1 = leftDist (pure (+1)) (pure (*10)) (pure 2 <|> pure 3)

rdExample1 :: Alternative f => Example (f Int)
rdExample1 = rightDist (pure (+1) <|> pure (*10)) (pure 2) (pure 3)
```

We can demonstrate a few properties of lists, `FlipAp` lists, and `runAlt`.

Lists are left-distributive, but `FlipAp` lists aren't

```
ldExample1 :: Example [Int]
ldExample1 :: Example (FlipAp [] Int)

[[3,4,20,30],[3,4,20,30]]
[FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,20,4,30]},FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,4,20,30]}]
```

Lists aren't right-distributive, but `FlipAp` lists are

```
rdExample1 :: Example [Int]
rdExample1 :: Example (FlipAp [] Int)

[[3,4,20,30],[3,20,4,30]]
[FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,20,4,30]},FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,20,4,30]}]
```

`Alt` is always left-distributive

```
map (runAlt id) ldExample1 :: Example [Int]
map (runAlt id) ldExample1 :: Example (FlipAp [] Int)

[[3,4,20,30],[3,4,20,30]]
[FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,4,20,30]},FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,4,20,30]}]
```

`Alt` is never right-distributive

```
map (runAlt id) rdExample1 :: Example [Int]
map (runAlt id) rdExample1 :: Example (FlipAp [] Int)

[[3,4,20,30],[3,20,4,30]]
[FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,4,20,30]},FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,20,4,30]}]
```

We can defile a right-distributive free alternative in terms of `FlipAp` and `Alt`.

```
runFlipAlt :: forall f g a. Alternative g => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> FlipAp (Alt f) a -> g a
runFlipAlt nt = runAlt nt . unFlipAp
```

`FlipAp` `Alt` is never left-distributive.

```
map (runFlipAlt id) ldExample1 :: Example [Int]
map (runFlipAlt id) ldExample1 :: Example (FlipAp [] Int)

[[3,20,4,30],[3,4,20,30]]
[FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,20,4,30]},FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,4,20,30]}]
```

`FlipAp` `Alt` is always right-distributive

```
map (runFlipAlt id) rdExample1 :: Example [Int]
map (runFlipAlt id) rdExample1 :: Example (FlipAp [] Int)

[[3,20,4,30],[3,20,4,30]]
[FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,20,4,30]},FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,20,4,30]}]
```

Up until now I haven't told you anything that you didn't already imply by saying that `liftAlt : f -> Alt f` is an `Alternative` homomorphism, but only for *left-distributive* Alternative instances. But I have shown you a free-alternative that isn't left-distributive (it's trivially right-distributive instead).

#### A structurally valid free `Alternative`

This section answers the bulk of your question, is there a *structurally* valid free `Alternative` that isn't left-distributive? Yes.

This isn't an efficient implementation; it's purpose is to demonstrate that it exists and that some version of it can be arrived at in a straight-forward manner.

To make a structurally valid free `Alternative` I am doing two things. The first is to create a data structure that can't represent any of the `Alternative` laws; if it can't represent the law then a structure can't be constructed independently of the type class to violate it. This is the same trick used to make lists structurally obey the `Alternative` associativity law; there's no list that can represent the left-associated `(x <|> y) <|> z`. The second part is to make sure the operations obey the laws. A list can't represent the left association law, but an implementation of `<|>` could still violate it, like `x <|> y = x ++ reverse y`.

The following structure can't be constructed to represent any of the `Alternative` laws.

```
{-# Language GADTs #-}
{-# Language DataKinds #-}
{-# Language KindSignatures #-}

data Alt :: (* -> *) -> * -> * where
    Alt :: Alt' empty pure plus f a -> Alt f a

--           empty   pure    plus
data Alt' :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> (* -> *) -> * -> * where
    Empty ::        Alt' True  False False f a
    Pure  :: a   -> Alt' False True  False f a
    Lift  :: f a -> Alt' False False False f a

    Plus  :: Alt' False pure1 False f a -> Alt' False pure2 plus2 f a -> Alt' False False True  f a
      -- Empty can't be to the left or right of Plus
      -- empty <|> x = x
      -- x <|> empty = x

      -- Plus can't be to the left of Plus
      -- (x <|> y) <|> z = x <|> (y <|> z)
    Ap    :: Alt' False False plus1 f (a -> b) -> Alt' empty False plus2 f a -> Alt' False False False f b
      -- Empty can't be to the left of `Ap`
      -- empty <*> f = empty

      -- Pure can't be to the left or right of `Ap`
      -- pure id <*> v = v     
      -- pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w = u <*> (v <*> w)
      -- pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)
      -- u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u
```

It's a `Functor`

```
instance Functor f => Functor (Alt' empty pure plus f) where
    fmap _ Empty       = Empty
    fmap f (Pure a)    = Pure (f a)
    fmap f (Plus a as) = Plus (fmap f a) (fmap f as)
    fmap f (Lift a)    = Lift (fmap f a)
    fmap f (Ap g a)    = Ap (fmap (f .) g) a

instance Functor f => Functor (Alt f) where
    fmap f (Alt a) = Alt (fmap f a)
```

And it's `Applicative`. Because the structure can't represent the laws, when we encounter a term containing one of the unpreventable expressions we're forced to convert it into something else. The laws tell us what to do.

```
instance Functor f => Applicative (Alt f) where
    pure a = Alt (Pure a)

    Alt Empty <*> _ = Alt Empty                          -- empty <*> f = empty
    Alt (Pure f) <*> (Alt x) = Alt (fmap f x)            -- pure f <*> x = fmap f x          (free theorem)
    Alt u <*> (Alt (Pure y)) = Alt (fmap ($ y) u)        -- u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u
    Alt f@(Lift _)   <*> Alt x@Empty      = Alt (Ap f x)
    Alt f@(Lift _)   <*> Alt x@(Lift _)   = Alt (Ap f x)
    Alt f@(Lift _)   <*> Alt x@(Plus _ _) = Alt (Ap f x)
    Alt f@(Lift _)   <*> Alt x@(Ap _ _)   = Alt (Ap f x)
    Alt f@(Plus _ _) <*> Alt x@Empty      = Alt (Ap f x)
    Alt f@(Plus _ _) <*> Alt x@(Lift _)   = Alt (Ap f x)
    Alt f@(Plus _ _) <*> Alt x@(Plus _ _) = Alt (Ap f x)
    Alt f@(Plus _ _) <*> Alt x@(Ap _ _)   = Alt (Ap f x)
    Alt f@(Ap _ _)   <*> Alt x@Empty      = Alt (Ap f x)
    Alt f@(Ap _ _)   <*> Alt x@(Lift _)   = Alt (Ap f x)
    Alt f@(Ap _ _)   <*> Alt x@(Plus _ _) = Alt (Ap f x)
    Alt f@(Ap _ _)   <*> Alt x@(Ap _ _)   = Alt (Ap f x)
```

All of those `Ap`s could be covered by a pair of view patterns, but it doesn't make it any simpler.

It's also an `Alternative`. For this we'll use a view pattern to divide the cases into the empty and non-empty cases, and an extra type to store the proof that they're non-empty

```
{-# Language ViewPatterns #-}

import Control.Applicative

data AltEmpty :: (* -> *) -> * -> * where
    Empty_    :: Alt' True  False False f a -> AltEmpty f a
    NonEmpty_ :: AltNE f a -> AltEmpty f a

data AltNE :: (* -> *) -> * -> * where
    AltNE :: Alt' False pure plus f a -> AltNE f a

empty_ :: Alt' e1 p1 p2 f a -> AltEmpty f a
empty_ x@Empty      = Empty_ x
empty_ x@(Pure _)   = NonEmpty_ (AltNE x)
empty_ x@(Lift _)   = NonEmpty_ (AltNE x)
empty_ x@(Plus _ _) = NonEmpty_ (AltNE x)
empty_ x@(Ap _ _)   = NonEmpty_ (AltNE x)

instance Functor f => Alternative (Alt f) where
    empty = Alt Empty

    Alt Empty <|> x = x                                 -- empty <|> x = x
    x <|> Alt Empty = x                                 -- x <|> empty = x
    Alt (empty_ -> NonEmpty_ a) <|> Alt (empty_ -> NonEmpty_ b) = case a <> b of AltNE c -> Alt c
      where
        (<>) :: AltNE f a -> AltNE f a -> AltNE f a
        AltNE (Plus x y) <> AltNE z = AltNE x <> (AltNE y <> AltNE z)  -- (x <|> y) <|> x = x <|> (y <|> z)
        AltNE a@(Pure _) <> AltNE b = AltNE (Plus a b)
        AltNE a@(Lift _) <> AltNE b = AltNE (Plus a b)
        AltNE a@(Ap _ _) <> AltNE b = AltNE (Plus a b)
```

`liftAlt` and `runAlt`

```
{-# Language RankNTypes #-}
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}

liftAlt :: f a -> Alt f a
liftAlt = Alt . Lift

runAlt' :: forall f g x empty pure plus a. Alternative g => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> Alt' empty pure plus f a -> g a
runAlt' u = go
  where
    go :: forall empty pure plus a. Alt' empty pure plus f a -> g a
    go Empty    = empty
    go (Pure a) = pure a
    go (Lift a) = u a
    go (Plus x y) = go x <|> go y
    go (Ap f x)   = go f <*> go x

runAlt :: Alternative g => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> Alt f a -> g a
runAlt u (Alt x) = runAlt' u x
```

This new `Alt f` doesn't provide either left-distribution or right-distribution for free, and therefore `runAlt id :: Alt f a -> g a` preserves how distributive `g` is.

Lists are still left-distributive, but `FlipAp` lists aren't.

```
map (runAlt id) ldExample1 :: Example [Int]
map (runAlt id) ldExample1 :: Example (FlipAp [] Int)

[[3,4,20,30],[3,4,20,30]]
[FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,20,4,30]},FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,4,20,30]}]
```

List's aren't right-distributive, but `FlipAp` lists still are

```
map (runAlt id) rdExample1 :: Example [Int]
map (runAlt id) rdExample1 :: Example (FlipAp [] Int)

[[3,4,20,30],[3,20,4,30]]
[FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,20,4,30]},FlipAp {unFlipAp = [3,20,4,30]}]
```

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/Cedev/3ef669f809b3c2e771e57efb8771899e) for this section

#### Structurally valid left-catch free `Alternative`

To control which laws we want we can add them to the structurally free alternative we made earlier.

To add left-catch we'll modify the structure so it can't represent it. Left catch is

(pure a) <|> x = pure a

To keep `Alt'` from representing it we'll exclude `pure` from what's allowed to the left of `Plus`.

```
--           empty   pure    plus
data Alt' :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> (* -> *) -> * -> * where
    Empty ::        Alt' True  False False f a
    Pure  :: a   -> Alt' False True  False f a
    Lift  :: f a -> Alt' False False False f a

    Plus  :: Alt' False False False f a -> Alt' False pure2 plus2 f a -> Alt' False False True  f a
      -- Empty can't be to the left or right of Plus
      -- empty <|> x = x
      -- x <|> empty = x

      -- Plus can't be to the left of Plus
      -- (x <|> y) <|> z = x <|> (y <|> z)

      -- Pure can't be to the left of Plus
      -- (pure a) <|> x = pure a

    ...
```

This results in a compiler error in the implementation of `Alternative Alt`

```
Couldn't match type ‘'True’ with ‘'False’
Expected type: Alt' 'False 'False 'False f a1
  Actual type: Alt' 'False pure2 plus2 f a1
In the first argument of ‘Plus’, namely ‘a’
In the first argument of ‘AltNE’, namely ‘(Plus a b)
```

Which we can fix by appealing to our new law, `(pure a) <|> x = pure a`

```
instance Functor f => Alternative (Alt f) where
    empty = Alt Empty

    Alt Empty <|> x = x                                 -- empty <|> x = x
    x <|> Alt Empty = x                                 -- x <|> empty = x
    Alt (empty_ -> NonEmpty_ a) <|> Alt (empty_ -> NonEmpty_ b) = case a <> b of AltNE c -> Alt c
      where
        (<>) :: AltNE f a -> AltNE f a -> AltNE f a
        AltNE a@(Pure _) <> _ = AltNE a                                -- (pure a) <|> x = pure a
        AltNE (Plus x y) <> AltNE z = AltNE x <> (AltNE y <> AltNE z)  -- (x <|> y) <|> x = x <|> (y <|> z)
        AltNE a@(Lift _) <> AltNE b = AltNE (Plus a b)
        AltNE a@(Ap _ _) <> AltNE b = AltNE (Plus a b)
```

Comment: It's pretty neat how "mechanical" this is; it makes it straightforward to enforce arbitrary laws according to typeclass laws and generate a free structure for...everything.  I've figured out one my own actually I think, that isn't mechanical and is instead more natural in that it doesn't use any type level predicates and existential types, but this answer is pretty nice for its "no cleverness required" kinda feel in translating arbitrary laws to the free structures.